# PySide when I display dialog in mainwindow, it interrupts my worker thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyside, pyside6

I have a main thread and a worker thread. A worker thread runs concurrently when a window widget is created.

The main window has buttons. When this button is pressed, QinputDialog is launched. However, at this time, the worker thread is stopped.

I want a thread that keeps running independently. How can I fix this?

this is my code

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import QThread
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
import time

class Worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self):
        for i in range(0,100):
            time.sleep(2)
            print(i)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton(parent=self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.button)
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.button.setText("BUTTON")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_clicked)
        self.click_count = 0

        self.worker = Worker()
        self.worker.start()
    def button_clicked(self):


        text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'input', 'input')
        if ok:
            pass


app = QApplication()
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: This phenomenon was only found in pyside6. I was able to solve it by changing to pyqt5 .

Comment: It seems to be a bug, I recommend you report it. I have also discovered that it is a PySide2 bug